What action types are supported by QuEra's Aquila on Amazon Braket?
I'm running a simple Bell's inequality example on Amazon Braket, using QuEra's Aquila.  The code below is taken almost exactly from their public textbook:  Braket algorithms -> textbook.
import numpy as np
from braket.devices import LocalSimulator
from braket.tracking import Tracker
from braket.experimental.algorithms.bells_inequality import (
    create_bell_inequality_circuits,
    get_bell_inequality_results,
    run_bell_inequality,
)
from braket.aws import AwsDevice

aquila = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:us-east-1::device/qpu/quera/Aquila")
tasks = run_bell_inequality([circAB, circAC, circBC], aquila, shots=1000) 
results, pAB, pAC, pBC = get_bell_inequality_results(tasks)


However, I'm unable to find any information at all on the following exception returned:
ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateQuantumTask operation: Device arn:aws:braket:us-east-1::device/qpu/quera/Aquila supports ['braket.ir.ahs.program'] action type, but the supplied action type is braket.ir.openqasm.program

I tried looking at the documentation on OpenQasm: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-openqasm-supported-features.html. But I can't find anything that would cause this to fail.  Is there a better way to troubleshoot this?

The Aquila device requires programs of type braket.ahs.AnalogHamiltonianSimulation, however you are trying to submit programs of type braket.circuits.Circuit.
See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/braket/latest/developerguide/braket-get-started-hello-ahs.html#braket-get-started-running-aquila-qpu
https://github.com/amazon-braket/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/analog_hamiltonian_simulation/01_Introduction_to_Aquila.ipynb


Gotcha.  So then it seems like the way we use QuEra through Braket, it is NOT possible to do something circuit-based optimization such as QAOA.  Correct?
